# regular expression dates

Tags: c#, regex

```
# Montag 28.03.2011
# Mi, 23.03.11

^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.][0-9]{4} or with \d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4}
```

works for 28.03.2011 but not for 23.03.11. can i automatically add 20 before 11 if year is just 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

How about the above

By the way this is just pattern matching so it will match invalid dates too. eg:30.02.2011

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one of the methods available in the `System.DateTime` namespace? You could use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

Comment: i have this too. I need regex for validation. Whole system is working with regex validation.

Comment: Why double check.. TryParseExact does the same your regex can do?
Sound to me like waste of time :)